# Bringing two different hosts each in two different subnets into a same subnet

Tags: ipv4, subnet, networking

Physical Network: 11.11.10.0(mask:255.255.248)

Subnet A 1 :11.11.10.0   IP A: 11.11.10.4 (mask:255.255.248 and 6 hosts)

Subnet B 2 :11.11.10.8   IP B: 11.11.10.11(mask:255.255.248 and 6 hosts)

Hi networking experts! I am trying to achieve something with subnetting and subnet masking. The goal is to bring both IP A and IP B in the same subnet. Is it possible by any means to do so via a new subnet mask??

I am really new to networking and I am having a hard time figuring it out!

Comment: You need to run your address through the steps in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499), which explains all you need to know about IPv4 addressing.

Comment: Smells like homework...

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to touch ip addressing scheme and just change subnet mask then you can change mask from 255.255.255.248 to 255.255.255.240 then both hosts will be in the same subnet which have range from 11.11.10.0 to 11.11.10.15.

Comment: Thank you for the response! But I shall avoid 11.11.10.2 and 11.11.10.10. Is it possible to bring (11.11.10.4 and 11.11.10.11) in a subnet and (11.11.10.2 and 11.11.10.10 ) in a different subnet?

Comment: No.  The usable addresses are 11.11.10.1 through 11.11.10.14

Comment: Like Ron said I will add also 11.11.10.0 is network id address and 11.11.10.15 is broadcast address so you cannot address those 2 ips to hosts.

Comment: "(11.11.10.4 and 11.11.10.11) in a subnet and (11.11.10.2 and 11.11.10.10 ) in a different subnet?" its not possible,